# Progress Ring fill clockwise

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system, lightning-renderer

I am using Brian's Progress Ring Component here-
https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/d1308608c0facdc626b85c9c248fc7af

It works great, however it fills in anticlockwise way. I have a requirement to fill  it clockwise.

I couldn't understand the document here-
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-ring/

Code to set values-->

```
({
    // Create SVG, path, populate with default values from controller
    render: function(component, helper) {
        var result = this.superRender(),
            xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
            updateContainer = result[0].querySelector("#progressContainer"),
            value = component.get("v.value"),
            dValue = "M 1 0 A 1 1 0 "+Math.floor(value / 50)+" 1 "+
                Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * value / 100)+" "+
                Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * value / 100)+" L 0 0",
            svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"svg"),
            path = document.createElementNS(xmlns,"path");
        svg.setAttributeNS(null,"viewBox", "-1 -1 2 2");
        path.setAttributeNS(null, "class", "slds-progress-ring__path");
        path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", dValue);
        svg.appendChild(path);
        updateContainer.appendChild(svg);
        return result;
    },
    // Update the progress bar on a rerender event
    rerender: function(component, helper) {
        var value = component.get("v.value"),
            dValue = "M 1 0 A 1 1 0 "+Math.floor(value / 50)+" 1 "+
                Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * value / 100)+" "+
                Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * value / 100)+" L 0 0",
            svg = component.getElement().querySelector("svg"),
            path = svg.childNodes[0];
        this.superRerender();
        path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", dValue);
    }
})
```

I tried interchanging cos and sin but didn't work, can anybody help.

Comment: Please use [edit] to format your code

Answer (score 2):

Just came across a similar requrement in my LWC project. Couldn't find anything helpful regarding this in the SLDS docs. But in [SLDS for React docs](https://react.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/progress-rings/), I found a useful property called `flowDirection="fill"`. 
This adds a css property `transform: scaleX(1) rotate(-90deg);` to the progressbar div to flip/mirror it.

So adding the same to my component did the trick.

```
<div class="slds-progress-ring__progress" style="transform: scaleX(1) rotate(-90deg);" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin={min} aria-valuemax={max} aria-valuenow={value}>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop a component with the same requirement. I found this solution:

```
//For example: 90%
var fillPercentage = 90;

var progressPath = 'M 1 0 A 1 1 0 {isLong} 0 {arcX} {arcY} L 0 0';

var isLong = fillPercentage > 50 ? 1 : 0;
var arcX = Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * fillPercentage / 100);
var arcY = Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * fillPercentage / 100) * -1;

progressPath = progressPath.replace('{isLong}', isLong);
progressPath = progressPath.replace('{arcX}', arcX);
progressPath = progressPath.replace('{arcY}', arcY);
```

The progressPath variable is taken from the Lightning Design System instructions you pasted, the only difference I applied is the "-1" multiplication in "arcY" variable since I have to get the opposite result.